# Error 403 when trying to login with auth.js in Docker container for SvelteKit project

Tags: docker, oauth, sveltekit

auth.js throws error 403, when inside a docker container

i am using auth.js in my sveltkit project and want to deploy it using docker on a rented server. When I start a development server on my machine, auth.js works perfectly fine, but when I start my docker container and try to log in, it throws an error 403 and i don't know why.

here is my docke.compose.yml

```
services:
  web:
    container_name: project_name
    image: username/project_name:1.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    env_file:
      - .env.production
    command: node /app/build/index.js
```

and the implementation of auth.js in sveltekit:

```js
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const auth = SvelteKitAuth({
    //@ts-ignore
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    //secret: AUTH_SECRET,
    trustHost: true,
    debug:true,
    providers: [
        Spotiy({
            clientId: SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET, 
        }),
        Google({
            clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
        }),
    ] as any,
    pages : {
        error: '/error'
    },
}) satisfies Handle;
```

Comment: hey, I am having this issue right now. did you find a solution for this?